# How to move JIRA Studio from hosted version to my own server?

Tags: jira

How to move JIRA Studio from hosted version to my own server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JIRA Studio](http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/studio/#) is a hosted service by Atlassian, and Atlassian also sells the applications individually.

Have you tried [asking their sales department](http://www.atlassian.com/about/contact.jsp)?  They'd almost certainly be more than willing to sell you more software and help you migrate.